# How do I import cv2

Tags: python, dll, opencv

I'm quite new to python and I'm currently working with opencv. After a few days working with cv2, the DLL load failed during import of cv2 error occurred. I read everything I could online, especially here, since there are similar questions, trying to solve the issue.
In particuar I have already tried to :

- paste the python3 DLL file in the Anaconda3 folder
- downgrade python version
- install/uninstall opencv via pip and conda
- uninstall and install anaconda from the beginning

without succeeding. I am using ST3, and here's some info about Conda and Python versions:

```
      conda version : 4.6.3
conda-build version : 3.17.6
     python version : 3.7.1.final.0
```

Furthermore, when installed opencv-python via pip, a new error was displayed while importing cv2:

```
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I tried to fix this issue (that appears to be related to numpy) as well, without succeeding.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have two separate installations of python, by chance? if you have vanilla python and anaconda both installed, you may by trying to run your code with a version of Python that doesn't have Python. execute `python --version` and see what comes back. If it isn't your Anaconda installation, this is likely the problem.

Comment: I only have Anaconda with its python version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding **Library\bin** to PATH environment variables: bin folder contains the needed DLL files!

Comment: Will do! I can only do that tomorrow, according to the website.